# show user id in a p tag

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i have a table for users and each row have a button. I want to show that user id inside a `p` tag when it is clicked, but it does not show

component :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Backend;
use App\Domains\Auth\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class Users extends Component
{


    public $selectedItem;

    public function selectItem($itemId)
    {
      $this->selectedItem = $itemId;


    }

    public function render()
    {
      $users = User::where('active' , '1')->get();
        return view('livewire.backend.users')->with('Users' , $users);
    }
}
```

and view :

```
<table class="datatable-init nk-tb-list nk-tb-ulist" data-auto-responsive="false">
    <thead>
        <tr class="nk-tb-item nk-tb-head">
            <th class="nk-tb-col">
                <span class="sub-text">Name </span>
            </th>
            <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb">
                <span class="sub-text">Balance</span>
            </th>
            <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                <span class="sub-text">Phone</span>
            </th>
            <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg">
                <span class="sub-text">KYC</span>
            </th>
            <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg">
                <span class="sub-text">Last login</span>
            </th>
            <th class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                <span class="sub-text">Status</span>
            </th>
            <th class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-tools text-right"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($Users as $user)
        <tr class="nk-tb-item">
            <td class="nk-tb-col">
                <div class="user-card">
                    <div class="user-info">
                        <span class="tb-lead">{{$user->name}}
                            <span class="dot dot-success d-md-none ml-1"></span>
                        </span>
                        <span>{{$user->email}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-mb">
                <span class="tb-amount">{{ number_format($user->balance)}}
                    <span class="currency">IRR</span>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                <span>{{$user->mobile}}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg" data-order="Email Verified - Kyc Unverified">
                <ul class="list-status">
                    <li>
                        @if ($user->isVerified())
                        <em class="icon text-success ni ni-check-circle"></em>
                        <span>mail</span>
                        @else
                        <em class="icon ni ni-alert-circle"></em>
                        <span>mail</span>
                        @endif
                    </li>
                    <li>

                        @if ($user->fullActive())
                        <em class="icon text-success ni ni-check-circle"></em>
                        <span>KYC </span>
                        @else
                        <em class="icon ni ni-alert-circle"></em>
                        <span>KYC</span>
                        @endif

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-lg">
                <span>{{jdate($user->last_login_at)}}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="nk-tb-col tb-col-md">
                @if ($user->isActive())
                <span class="tb-status text-success">Active</span>
                @else
                <span class="tb-status text-danger">Deactive</span>
                @endif

            </td>
            <td class="nk-tb-col nk-tb-col-tools">
                <ul class="nk-tb-actions gx-1">
                    <li class="nk-tb-action-hidden">
                        <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/2/mark/0" name="confirm-item" class="d-inline">
                            @csrf
                            <button typr="button" class="btn btn-trigger btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Deactive">
                                <em class="icon ni ni-wallet-fill"></em>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nk-tb-action-hidden">
                        <button wire:click="selectItem({{$user->id}})" type="button" class="btn btn-trigger btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Send Email">
                            <em class="icon ni ni-mail-fill"></em>
                        </button>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nk-tb-action-hidden">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-trigger btn-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Suspend">
                            <em class="icon ni ni-user-cross-fill"></em>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div class="drodown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-icon btn-trigger" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <em class="icon ni ni-more-h"></em>
                            </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                                <ul class="link-list-opt no-bdr">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <em class="icon ni ni-focus"></em>
                                            <span>Quick View</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <em class="icon ni ni-eye"></em>
                                            <span>View Details</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <em class="icon ni ni-repeat"></em>
                                            <span>Transaction</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <em class="icon ni ni-activity-round"></em>
                                            <span>Activities</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="divider"></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <em class="icon ni ni-shield-star"></em>
                                            <span>Reset Pass</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <em class="icon ni ni-shield-off"></em>
                                            <span>Reset 2FA</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">
                                            <em class="icon ni ni-na"></em>
                                            <span>Suspend User</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
  <p>selected item : {{$selectedItem}}</p>
<!-- Modal Trigger Code -->
```

what is problem?

Comment: Your markup appears correct. Have you checked for errors in your console or the network tab in your browser dev tools?

Comment: @Unflux Yes, but it does not show any errors

Comment: The errors may be in browser network tab because it sends an ajax call, but anyway in this given code there are no errors.... you simply set a variable on click... nothing happens actually with your code

Comment: @lewis4uThere is no error there either When I click the button, nothing appears in the network tab

Comment: Is there a `form` element in your view somewhere?

Comment: @Unflux yes in this page i have a form

Comment: Add `type="button"` to your `<button>` elements.

Comment: @Unflux i'm added...It still does not work :(

Comment: Can you provide your entire view and component code in your question?

Comment: @Unflux yes i'm added to question

Comment: Is that your entire view? You should only have one root-element in your Livewire blades (here you have a table-tag and a p-tag). And the `wire:key` should be on the `<tr>` element as the root element within the loop.

Comment: Your code works but only if as @Qirel has pointed out, you wrap your code in a single root element (i.e. `<div> ... your code here ... </div>`.

Comment: @Unflux  @Qirel  I use the datatable plugin and put the whole table in a `div` tag and in this case everything is fine and it works but when I click on the button and it shows id in tag `p` The table becomes a simple table and it looks like I did not use the database plugin!

Answer (score 1):

To not confuse Livewire, you should use `wire:key` on elements in a loop.You should use `wire:key` on elements. This also means that you should have `wire:key` in your HTML `<td>`.

try below

```php
@foreach ($Users as $user)
 <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
    <td wire:key="{{ $loop->index}}">
                 <button wire:click="selectItem({{$user->id}})" class="btn">
        <em class="icon ni ni-mail-fill"></em>
      </button>
    </td>
@endforeach
```

- https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting

Comment: change this `<td wire:key="{{ $loop->index}}">` to thias `<td wire:key="{{ $user->id}}">` and try

Comment: again It does not work...I tried every way I could, but it still doesn't work. It took me a long time

Comment: did you add liveWire's `css` and `js` in the base.blade.php file?

Comment: where did you get this from `$selectedItem`

Comment: i'm defined that in User Component

Comment: I have added one new answer try it hope this will work for you